Issues with Dropdown Menu in Jetpack Compose
I have a DropdownMenu composable in my app, and I want the DropdownMenuItems to have the exact same width as the Button which triggers their expansion.
This is what I've written:
Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
            .padding(bottom = 28.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Max no. of turns:  ",
            fontSize = 18.sp
        )
        
        Column {
            OutlinedButton(
                onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
                shape = RectangleShape,
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                ) {
                    Text(text = gameUiState.maxNoOfTurns.toString())

                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown,
                        contentDescription = "Dropdown Menu Icon"
                    )
                }
            }

            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
            ) {
                for (i in 1..10) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = i.toString()) },
                        onClick = {
                            onSelectionChange(i)
                            expanded = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

and this is what I have right now:

Please help!

Your dropdown container can adjust to each item's width and takes the max. So if you manipulate each items width, you can have the dropdown have the correct with and each item have the correct touch/click area:

Track your input container's size:
var inputSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
Listen to the input size changes in that container's modifier:

.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
   inputSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
}


Then you can use in the loop with DropdownMenuItems:

modifier = Modifier
   .width(inputSize.width),

NB: I have used this in JetBrains Compose but its compatible with JetPack Compose, with a few adjustments

You can wrap your Column in a BoxWithConstraints. Then you can access its maxWidth and set the width of your dropdown accordingly:
DropdownMenu(
    expanded = expanded,
    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(this@BoxWithConstraints.maxWidth),
) {
    // ...
}

